# Can I use any javascript lib for Angular 2 projects without adaptation?

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, bower

We are facing a big issue to find rich plugins for our new Angular 2 project. When can we find such tools ? How can we use any existing Javascript lib without waiting for its adaptation ?

Answer (score 0):

To include a JavaScript library in your TypeScript application you must first include it in your HTML file (index.html) as a script tag. for ex.

```
<script href="assets/js/jquery.highlight-5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To use the library you must add the following to one of your ts files:

```
declare var libraryVar: any;
```

Then you can use it's methods.

for ex. libraryVar.method(param);

Comment: without the need to make any adaptation to respect angular 2 archtiecture ? I am talking about these hundreds of libraries I was using when working on Angular 1 or native Js

Comment: Angular 1 was based on javascript and Angular 2 is based on typescript.
You can't expect every javascript lib to work with angular 2. you can use above code to add any external lib and use it by typescript syntax.